# Error with RStudio's RPresentation and taucharts

Tags: r, rstudio, presentation

The following error is shown in Rpresentation (From RStudio) 
`<!-htmlpreserve->` when rendering a tauchart on one of the presentation slides.

Whereas with ioslides there is no error and the graph is plotted nicely and keeps all its interactivity.

Do I need to add an additional parameter in the chunk options? Or do I need to specifically assign print to the object?

Code:

````
```{r,warning=FALSE,error=FALSE,message=FALSE,echo=FALSE}
tauchart(df) %>% 
tau_stacked_bar(x="x",y="y",color="color") %>%
tau_legend() %>% tau_tooltip()
```
````

Comment: I'll give it a whirl ASAP but it might be better to file a github issue vs post a Q on SO, esp since it's not even in CRAN yet ;-)

Comment: so it may be that htmlwidgets & Rpres do not get along: https://twitter.com/rstudio/status/594227156319862785

Comment: Ok, thanks for looking at this. Will use ioslides for the time being.

Comment: I filed an issue for you that you can track if so desired: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/taucharts/issues/53